# Cannot download a webpage using download.file in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I tried the following codes to download a html file. The code runs without error but the file returned is of very small size (~2kb) and cannot be opened.

```
url <- "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/english/Horse/OtherHorse.aspx?HorseNo=L042#htop"
download.file(url, destfile)
```

I am not sure if the connection speed affects whether download.file can return the correct result because sometimes the webpage can be downloaded after several tries. Any help or alternative solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about just `rvest::read_html`?

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of clean up to do, but here's the basic method

```
library(rvest)

read_html(url) %>% 
html_nodes(xpath ='/html/body/div/form/table[3]') %>% 
html_table(fill=T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I also tried rvest::read_html but had the same problem. I don't know whether it is because the html needs to load a lot of javascript and that causes the problem.